# JAVA Crash - hs_err_pid*.log

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I have a system installed with ubuntu 18.04.1, Eclipse Photon Release (4.8.0) and Oracle Java 1.8.
Java gets crashed whenever I start my eclipse. Then it generates a log file named as `hs_err_pid*.log` (eg : `hs_err_pid1773.log`).

Eclipse gets closed as soon as java crashes.

Could you guys please help me to solve this. I suspect this is because of GTK version.

Any idea...?

***These are the starting few lines of hs_err_pid1773.log***

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f0937e2fa22, pid=1773, tid=0x00007f0935657700

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_181-b13) (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.181-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
V  [libjvm.so+0x5cea22]  G1UpdateRSOrPushRefOopClosure::do_oop(unsigned int*)+0x42

Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

Comment: Will you post the result of: `java -version` command?

Comment: Yes, this is the result - java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

Comment: I had the same problem and I deleted the `.metadata` folder from my workspace and the error disappeared